# Canon EF vs Canon EF-S lens

Tags: equipment-recommendation, canon, kit-lens

I was wondering:

Other than the fact that EF-S lenses are targeted to cropped bodies, and can not be used on full frames.

(Supposedly if there was L series for the EF-S) Would the EF lenses be superior than EF-S?

What about comparing two non L lenses?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the advantages to using EF-S lenses on Canon APS-C cameras?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18891/what-are-the-advantages-to-using-ef-s-lenses-on-canon-aps-c-cameras)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between EF and EF-S lenses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/380/what-is-the-difference-between-ef-and-ef-s-lenses)

Answer (score 4):

Many EF lenses (especially L series) are going to be of higher quality than EF-S lenses based on marketing economics.  The market willing to pay more for a quality lens also likely has paid more for a higher end camera (for example 5DmkIII).

There is one technical aspect why EF lenses would be better than EF-S lenses on crop bodies.  A smaller sensor is going to encounter fewer of the quality problems at the edge of the image.  So an EF lens on, for example, a 7D, will see less light fall off, less aberration, and less distortion, because it is not picking up near the edge where lenses generally exhibit their weaknesses.

Comment: So it would make sense to stick with EF lenses in general.

Comment: @Bill, Sort of... if money isn't an issue and if there *is* an equivalent EF lens. But EF equivalents to the EF-S 10-22mm, 15-85mm and 17-55 for example don't really exist (and where similar EF lenses like the 16-35mm or 17-40mm exist, they have other trade-offs like much smaller zoom range and much bigger price-tags).

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily true to say that an EF-S lens on an APS-C body (such as the EOS 7D) will be inferior to an EF lens which has an equivalent angle-of-view on a full-frame body (such as the EOS 5D Mk II).

For instance, the EF-S 10-22mm lens is highly regarded, and some even rate it as better than the EF 17-40mm L-series lens. (To be fair, both are about the same price.)

Similarly, the EF-S 17-55mm lens is often said to be as good as an L-series lens in terms of optical performance. (Again, the price reflects this quality.)

If you're a fan of comparing raw optical performance of Canon lenses, take a look at lens review sites such as:

- [Photozone](http://www.photozone.de/reviews)
- [The Digital Picture](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-Zoom-Lens-Reviews.aspx)

Of course, most of these sites will remind you that lens quality is less important than just getting out there and taking interesting pictures.