# What's a good and cheap digital camera for capturing moving objects?

Tags: camera-recommendation

I'm an amateur photographer. I own a Sony DSCT200, and i'm looking for something better. I need a camera that can clearly capture moving objects, which mine fails to do even with most trivial things, like people running or a dog turning its head.

By moving objects, I'll stress I don't expect to capture anything faster than a car, but I look to be able to capture flying birds, and even small insects such as butterflies, both in close and far range. I also hope to get clear shots while moving, as in a train or car.

Video capture capabilites are desirable, but not a must. What is the best bet I can take nowadays that'll satisfy my needs?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Lin. Welcome to Stack Exchange. We don't really do on-demand product research here, and suggestions for specific camera models tend to get out of date quickly. Take a look at [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for ways to rephrase the question so that you can find what you're looking for _and_ so that it'll be useful in the long term.

Comment: Rather than ask what camera to buy, it may well be better to ask what features to look for in a camera to support what you want to achieve. Those features can then by plugged into one of several camera hardware sites to get some direct recommendations. As it is, this question is very likely to get closed as being off topic.

Answer (score 2):

Using a cheap compact for moving objects is a hard proposition but, as a general advice, I'd suggest looking for a compact camera that works well in low light (such as the ones mentioned in [How do I tell which point-and-shoot cameras take good low light photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1373/how-do-i-tell-which-point-and-shoot-cameras-take-good-low-light-photos)) but using it on scenes with lots of light.

This will allow the cameras to use lower ISOs and fast enough shutter speeds that will help freezing the movements in the scene.

Keep in mind that a bigger issue with cheaper compacts is their slow focusing speed. In order to circumvent this you've better pre-focus on your subject and then wait with the shutter button half pressed until that "decisive moment" happens.