# I want a point and shoot to take pictures inside an auditorium without a flash?

Tags: point-and-shoot

Is there a point and shoot camera that will allow me to take pictures in an auditorium without using flash?

Comment: Yes: any point and shoot will take pictures in an auditorium without flash. Or in other words: you need to be more specific about your requirements - two very important things are what is happening in the auditorium and how far away from it are you likely to be?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the subject and setting?  For instance, are you trying to photograph a music performance in an indoor stage, light by stage lighting?

Comment: As long as you don't mind them being dark and blurry there are a bunch that will! Even with it, most P&S camera's don't have a powerful enough flash to reach the front of an auditorium from most of the seats.

Comment: "I want a point and shoot to take pictures inside an auditorium without a flash?" also unfortunately is not really a question, the answer would have to be "well, we don't know; do you?".

Comment: What is your question really?
- How to use a point and shoot without triggering flash? There should be a menu or dial option (lightning drawn over with a line).
- Is there a point and shoot that is SENSITIVE enough in an auditorium without flash? It depends on the lighting. The easiest would be: ask a friend who has a good DSLR camera to make a good shot without flash (one that is acceptable for you), then provide us with Shutter+Aperture+ISO he used, and then we might be able to help you selecting a point and shoot.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [Sony RX10](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FRHTSMW) is among the best point'n'shoot cameras in a dark auditorium because it has a relatively large image sensor (1") and what's even better it has a [f/2,8 constant aperture](http://www.digitalcamerareview.com/default.asp?newsID=5428&news=sony+rx10+f2.8+constant+zoom+24-200mm+lens) zoom lens to let you "get close". The constant aperture means that you have the wide aperture in use through the full zoom range.

The bad news is, it is not cheap. Amazon currently sells it for $1300.

There is a question *["how do I tell which point-and-shoot cameras can take good low light photos?"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1373/how-do-i-tell-which-point-and-shoot-cameras-take-good-low-light-photos)* which may be of help when you try to find a camera cheaper than the Sony RX10.

Comment: You are right, but it looks like a DSRL... In a lot of places you will not be permitted entry with it (Pepsi Center in Denver, for example).

Comment: Should the question be edited to read "Is there a point-and-shoot camera that I can sneak into an event venue that will allow me to take pictures without using flash of an entertainment event in a large venue that likely has *no photography allowed* printed on the ticket?"

Answer (score 1):

Disable your flash, via menu options, and take the picture (if your uncertain how to do so, take a look at your camera's manual). Most compacts include an icon with a thunderbold with a slash over it, [like this](http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/no-flash.png), on its mode dial wheel. That's the one you should use.

Comment: Enabling spot metering if it's available is also useful, as concert situations typically have a brightly lit stage surrounded by blackness, which will give bad exposure results under default autoexposure settings.