# What rechargeable batteries are best for a Nikon L26?

Tags: nikon, battery, coolpix

I am using Nikon Coolpix L26 Camera. I am planning for a small vacation and wanted to make use of my old Nikon Coolpix L26 camera. The problem with the camera is that after couple of snaps battery is getting exhausted. Currently, I am using the gp rechargable batteries.
[image]

The [Nikon L26](http://www.cnet.com/uk/products/nikon-coolpix-l26/) camera uses AA size batteries. I am looking for some nice durable batteries. I am not expecting too much backup, but some what better than the current gp batteries which I am using now. I did my homework and shortlisted the [**eneloop**](http://main.panasonic-eneloop.eu/?q=products&field_batterie_cat_tid=41) batteries.

Being a complete noob I can't rely on my short-listings. Can you suggest which batteries are suitable for this type of camera configuration?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that *after couple of snaps battery is getting exhausted* ? Are your rechargeable battery old ? Are you taking photo in room temperature ? What do you want by "durable" ?

Comment: Related : http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1892/how-can-i-tell-when-its-time-to-replace-not-just-change-my-rechargeable-batte

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I mean the batteries are not up to the mark. Seems that they are not working properly even after recharge. Durable I  mean long lasting powerful rechargeable batteries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your rechargeable batteries are dead.

In general, as you have already found, low discharge batteries such as the eneloop batteries are the more appropriate for a camera.

Your Nikon L26 accepts 2 x AA (Alkaline, NiMH or Lithium), so I would use "low-discharge" AA rechargeable batteries with a capacity of 2000 mAh or higher.

You have two choices :

- Rechargeable batteries with high capacity (>2500 mAh) and a fair number of recharge cycles (500). For example : [http://www.amazon.com/Panasonic-BK-4HCCA8BA-Pre-Charged-Rechargeable-Batteries/dp/B00JHKSL0K/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JHKSL0K)
- Rechargeable batteries with regular capacity (2000 mAh) and more recharge cycles (2000). For example : [http://www.amazon.com/Panasonic-BK-4MCCA4BA-Pre-Charged-Rechargeable-Batteries/dp/B00JHKSMJK/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JHKSMJK)

Higher capacity batteries will make your camera last longer, but you won't be able to recharge them as many times.

Try to swap your battery when they are about 30% discharged. They will last longer (discharging them fully decreases their life expectancy).

Your camera specifications indicate a CIPA score of 200 (more on CIPA here : http://www.cipa.jp/camera/dc-std/battery_e.html). The *real* number of pictures you can take depends heavily of your camera usage so this number is only an indication. However, if with new batteries your camera die on you after only 20 shots, it would probably be a camera issue.

Comment: I thought full discharging was only bad for Lithium-ion batteries... is there a source for this being the case with NiMH?

Comment: Also note that if you'll be exhausting and recharging the batteries within a couple of days or so, you'll be better off with the higher capacity of non-low-self-discharge types. If you will be slowly draining them for longer than a week, then the low-self-discharge have an advantage.

Comment: Fully discharging an NiMH battery is probably impossible as "intelligent" hardware using those kind of batteries automatically detect when it is about to happen and shutdown the device to protect the battery. If not, it will definitely damage battery cells (you can even invert its polarity : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel–metal_hydride_battery). Source about life expectancy and depth of discharge : http://priuschat.com/threads/understanding-nimh-hypercycles-to-prolong-prius-hv-battery-life.64978/ (I have a better link but can't find it)

Comment: While I agree with all of this, I'm surprised you've made no mention of charging and chargers. A quality charger is at least as important as the battery quality because a good charger can appropriately cycle cells to keep them in good health, measure voltage and charge/discharge rate to help identify bad cells or old less-good cells, and to completely charge the cell to 100% to help maintain cell quality and extend battery life.

Comment: @DanWolfgang, it is indeed an important choice. I had to buy one time a third party charger for a Canon battery (LP-E6) : it killed the battery. After this incident, I have always used a charger of the battery's brand. Innocently, I think that the battery constructor is the most able to provide a good charger. Is it wrong ? I know that you can find fancy chargers with plenty of options/display but I never had any problem with the one provided by the battery constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Nikon Coolpix L610 camera - and - just so you know, my manual says to to batteries no higher than 2300 mAh. I am shopping now for some new batteries and came across your question. I am going to get some LSD - low self discharge batteries this time.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Please consider in future to make such remarks as comments to the question, not as an answer.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is you can't actually choose the best rechargeable batteries so easy. 
I had the same problem with my Canon EOS 500D. After 20-30 snaps my batteries were gone. Now i'm using Panasonic eneloops after reading Olivier's feedback. Choose is yours, just surf the net and you'll find the answer. I've found infos about all of the best [here](http://topchoice.best/main-review/top-rechargeable-batteries)

I hope it would be useful, good luck!

Comment: This makes no sense, as of course the Canon camera does not use this type of battery. "Eugene" is a spammer, paid to post legitimate-looking messages in forums containing links to this site.

Comment: Canon EOS 500D isn't using theese, but flash uses. I made a mistake once and now im spammer.