# How can I charge my Canon 760D / LP-E17 battery while hiking in the mountains?

Tags: canon, battery, usb, charger

I'm going hiking in the Himalyas next month. I just purchased a new 760D body. The problem is, I cannot purchase spare batteries because they are not being sold in India. I can import them from the US, but it costs $250 to get it shipped here. I regret not purchasing a 70D body.

I won't have access to power source for atleast 10 days or so, and specs suggests this camera can only take about 440 shots. It will be even worse if I take long exposure Astro shots or shoot videos. I can't purchase DC Coupler and attached a external power source because even the DC coupler is not being sold here.

Can can I charge the batteries? I can carry USB power source.

Comment: related: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4190/solar-charging-systems-for-camera-gear?rq=1

Comment: also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/38110/canon-dslr-usb-chargers/38129#38129

Comment: Can a battery be charged whilst inside the body using a USB lead?   My D80 allows this.

Comment: I think the basic problem here applies even if you had a handful of spare batteries. You'd want to be able to charge them, not hope that you had enough and that they retained charge for the duration of the trip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out a way to charge my Canon 760's LP-E17 battery with 5v USB output and was able to go 15 days without power. I was able to charge my batteries 12 times using Xiaomi 16000mah power bank.

**Here's how I did it.**

1. Purchased Neweer USB battery charger for Canon 1100D batteries. (Link: [http://www.amazon.com/Neewer-Battery-Charger-LP-E10-Rechargeable/dp/B00ZHJ8XHQ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ZHJ8XHQ))
2. Opened the charger and hacked a piece of copper. Works as flawlessly as the original charger.

[image: Neweer charger mod for Canon LP-E17 battery]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a small power inverter and a solar panel would serve your needs. This would allow you to use your existing charger regardless of whether you have access to power or not

Comment: Do you have any specific recommendation?

Comment: Sorry but I don't have anything specific for you. Just know it is a viable option for you