# Which AA rechargeable batteries work best for Nikon SB-600 speedlight?

Tags: nikon, flash, battery

I am interested what is your experience with this speedlight with regards to the type of batteries you use.

Can you recommend the batteries providing shortest recycle time and max number of flashes?

Comment: Duplicate: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/570/what-attributes-should-i-look-for-when-buying-batteries-for-a-flash