# My Flash doesn't Flash

Tags: flash

I have a Sunpak PF30x on a Nikon D40. I just put in new batteries and the flash worked great for two shots. After that, the flash doesn't pop. I tried turning the camera off and the flash off then turning them both on again. The "test/charge" light is lit up but no pop. Is it really chewing through batteries that fast?

**Update** I've notice if the camera sits overnight,I can get two pops out of the flash,then nothing.

Comment: What kind of batteries are you using?

Comment: @Reid kirkland.

Comment: I've noticed that the images when the flash doesn't go off, the value for "Flash Mode" in the picture info is blank. When it does go off, the value is "Optional, TTL"

Comment: Right - alkaline? NiMH? other?

Comment: @Reid alkaline.

Comment: Alkaline batteries will perform very poorly in high-current applications like a flash; it might very well be chewing through your batteries in only two shots. See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/570/what-attributes-should-i-look-for-when-buying-batteries-for-a-flash for more.

Comment: I just tried NiMH. Same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few possibilities that I can think of...

1. The flash overheated and just needs to cool. This is is very unlikely since you only fired off two.
2. You're above the sync speed on your shutter.
3. The flash wasn't needed for the current exposure settings.

Does the test button trigger it? Does your built-in flash fire?

Comment: Sometimes the test button works, sometimes it doesn't. Right now it's not.

Comment: You may a faulty flash then. Is it new? If so, you might be able to get a warranty repair on it or at least have it checked out. That model supports other cameras as well, so if you have a friend with a different brand, you could get them to try it.

Comment: Is is old, and I did have a buddy try. Same luck. I thought perhaps it was a poor brand.

Comment: Well, they don't last forever, but I've had little problems with them before. That now leaves the possibility that the flash tube is done in or that the flash itself is. It would seem the latter given that it sometimes will work.